# Remove whitespace using Imagick and PHP, then save as transparent PNG

Tags: php, imagick

I've got an image and want to remove all whitespace around it, and then save it as a transparent PNG. I'm using Imagick in PHP to do so, but my script doesn't seem to function properly.

```
<?php
$im = new Imagick("http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/14688888-2862.jpg");

$im->borderImage("#ffffff", 20, 20);
$im->trimImage(0.3);

$im->setImagePage($im->getImageWidth(), $im->getImageHeight(), 0, 0);
$im->setImageFormat("png");

header("Content-Type: image/" . $im->getImageFormat());
echo $im->getImageBlob();
?>
```

What do I need to do to remove all white (and close to white) areas at the borders? And when that is done, can I easily resize the image to crop all of the transparency?

Comment: Can you post what the image you are generating is? Also setImagePage is called incorrectly it should probably be $im->setImagePage($im->getImageWidth(), $im->getImageHeight(), 0, 0);

Comment: @Danack: I've updated the code to use setImagePage correctly, tnx. 
Right now I'm still getting a 480x480 px PNG, which looks the same as the source at http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/14688888-2862.jpg.

Answer (score 1):

The fuzz factor needs to be a quantum scaled value, not just for this function but almost all functions that take 'fuzz' as a parameter.

i.e. you need to scale it up to the quantum range.

```
$im->trimImage(0.3 * \Imagick::getQuantum());
```

Or if you are using an earlier version of Imagick that doesn't have that method, then instead do:

```
$range = $image->getQuantumRange();
$image->trimImage(0.3 * $range['quantumRangeLong']);
```

The reason for this is to allow precise control over the pixel matching. If the value was passed in as a float value in the range 0-1 it would not possible to have exact control over the value that was used for matching.

By instead using an integer value (for versions of Imagick that do not have HDRI enabled) it allows you to precisely control the values that are compared for the operation.

Comment: That does trim the image down quite a bit, but still leaves whitespace around the round corners. How to fix that as well?

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do that programmatically to your satisfaction. You have a JPG image, so the edges are not crisp. Any attempts to do what you want to do will either remove too much of the phone, or leave blocky white stuff around it. You might find some script here http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/

Comment: I see quite good results with the this command line script: http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/12/convert-white-to-transparent.html.

So I'd think this should be doable in a PHP environment as well.

Comment: @RuudKok If you get it to work, could you post the code to github.com/danack/imagick-demos as an Issue, so that I can add an example at http://phpimagick.com

Answer (score -1):

You need something like an autocrop based on pixel values, I think this will help:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim

you might also like:
http://fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/autotrim/index.php

source:
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=10843

Comment: Please don't just dump links. The question asker has the correct function to use, it just isn't working correctly for them.